# Is it possible to use node.js/Javascript to calculate anything in an accurate way?

Tags: javascript, math, node.js

Is it possible to use node.js/Javascript to calculate anything in an accurate way?

I had like to write some statistical library..

EDIT:
 I like to do develop a library that is accurate as much as matlab is accurate.

If so, do I need to develop my own math library in order to do so, or can I use some available javascript libraries?

Comment: What is "accurate"? 1 or 2 decimal places, or do you need more?

Comment: Probably non-floating-point math.

Comment: Given the leeway afforded by the words "possible", "anything", and "accurate", I'm pretty sure the answer is definitely **yes**.  If you were to ask a question about whether it's *practical* to calculate *something in particular* to a *specific degree of accuracy*, the answer might be different.

Comment: What is it that you want to calculate?

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is turing complete, so yes, it is possible to compute any computable function to arbitrary levels of precision.

This answer may not be especially useful, but your question is too vague for anything else.

Comment: I like to do develop a library that is accurate as much as matlab is accurate.

Comment: @ciochPep: You can do that, because javascript is turing complete.

Comment: I see, but do I need to develop my own math library in order to do so, or can I use some available javascript libraries?

Comment: @ciochPep: That's a different question. If you want answers to that question, post a question to that effect.